# My angular controller is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I m new in Anguar js .

I have created a **controller** and **pass the data** but my **controller** not working can u please help me .

**My code is this**

**Angular code is**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.person=[
      {name:"Raj", gender:"M"},
      {name: "raja", gender:"M"},
      {name:"sevitra" gender:"F"}
      ]


  });
```

**HTML
Code is**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div controller="myController">
      <a href="javascript:void()">
        <button>Add New Field</button>
      </a>
      <div class="advance-menu-wraper">
        <ul>
          <li>
          {{"person[0].name"}} + {{"person[0].gender"}}
            <div class="head-text">Field 1:</div>
            <div class="description-text">
              <a href="#">How many staff members are proficient in Oracla programing</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="head-text">Field 2:</div>
            <div class="description-text">
              <form name="addForm">
                <textarea rows="2"></textarea>
                <div class="send-btn">
                  <button>
                    <i class="fa fa-check">Submit</i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ffq0lzR97eneIUXEnZyG?p=preview)**

Comment: Shouldn't that {{"person.name[0]"}} + {{"persone.gender"}} be {{"person[0].name"}} + {{"person[0].gender"}}?

Comment: Hello @John i have do this but not working please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression won't work:

```
{{"person[0].name"}} + {{"person[0].gender"}}
```

yields: "{{"person[0].name"}} + {{"person[0].gender"}}" in your html.

The correct expression would be:

```
 {{person[0].name + person[0].gender}}
```

Moreover you have an syntax error in your array. The last object misses a comma.

This is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/R9ojp8TWd7AloRrlPlZh?p=preview

Comment: That's better {{ person.0.name + person.0.gender }}

Comment: hi @Nilolas i want to add some dynamic data in my list how is do please help me my url is http://plnkr.co/edit/e69pNXXE0Tg9EHUAfcYy?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the ngController directive

change

```
<div controller="myController">
```

to

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `{name:"sevitra" gender:"F"}` should be `{name:"sevitra", gender:"F"}`
2. `controller="myController"` should be `ng-controller="myController"`
3. `{{"person[0].name"}} + {{"person[0].gender"}}` should be `{{person[0].name}} + {{person[0].gender}}`

Answer (score 2):

three things which need to be change that i can see

change the controller to

```
app.controller('myController', [ '$scope',function($scope) {
```

change the `<div controller="MyController">` to `<div ng-controller="MyController"`

and in the `{{ " Person[0].Name "}}` and `{{ " Person[0].gender "}}` remove the quote marks so it becomes `{{Person[0].Name}}` and `{{Person[]0.gender}}`